# Handle iframe in React with refs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe, ref

I am trying to set the content of an iframe in a React component. I have a component in which contains a `handleStatementPrint` function which has to be called when the iframe finishes loading. That function must print loaded iframe content - pdf file accessed with URL `this.props.pdfs.url` . Already iframe content is loaded and I can see pdf file in iframe, but I need to pass iframe content with refs but don't know how to do that correctly. I know that I need to use `componentDidMount`, but don't know that to write in here.

***Component which must have iframe content***:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import IframeComponent from './components/Iframe';

class MainComponent extends Component {

  handleStatementPrint = () => {
    const iframePdf = this.iframePdf.contentWindow;
    if (this.iframePdf !== undefined) {
       const iframePdf = this.iframePdf.contentWindow;
       iframePdf.print();
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="container">

        {
          this.props.pdfs &&
            <iframe
              ref={(frame) => { this.iframePdf = frame }}
              src={this.props.pdfs.url}
              title="iFramePdf"
              type="application/pdf"
              >
            </iframe>
        }

      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Statement;
```

***Iframe component***:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class IframeComponent extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // Load iframe content 
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        
         <Iframe />

      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Iframe;
```

I'm tried this examples:

[Basic react iframe with onLoad handler](https://gist.github.com/iest/3b571a6ddcdd9ddab3cf)

[Handling of iframes in React](https://medium.com/@ebakhtarov/handling-of-iframes-in-react-f038be46ac24)

Iframe content is coming from fetch API, but I can access iframe and can see that content is perfectly loaded using ref. Problem: need to load that content in `componentDidMount` method before calling `handleStatementPrint` function from another component which can print loaded iframe content.

Questions:

1. So how to pass correctly iframe content with refs to load content in componentDidMountmethod?
2. How to pass loaded content from `componentDidMount` method in *MainComponent* functions, to do actions with loaded content?

Answer (score 0):

This is how refs works:

```
<MyComponent ref={(c) => { this.myComponent = c; }} />
```

After component is MOUNTED you gain access to the component itself and its method:

```
this.myComponent.myMethod();
```

Comment: I tried this, but how to load iframe content in componentDidMount method, and then in another component handleStatementPrint function access iframe content and do actions with it?

Comment: Iframe content comes from the same origin ? If it isn't you can't access to the iFrame content directly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Iframe content's src url is coming from fetch API, but i can access iframe and can see that content(pdf URL) is perfectly loaded using ref. Problem: need to load that content in componentDidMount method before calling handleStatementPrint function from another component wich can print loaded iframe content.

Comment: load content in componentDidMount isn't a issue, i suppose. You can store loaded content in a class variable or, if it's serializable, directly in the state.